# std::string no reconocido

Tags: c++

Estoy declarando una serie de clases en C++, y de repente no me reconoce **std::string**, y el programa no compila. Da el siguiente error:

```
Lapiz.h:25:30: error: 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

He probado con `#include <string>` e `#include <string.h>` sin éxito. Además, nunca lo he puesto y siempre ha funcionado. No sé si es por la hora o por qué, pero debería dejar esto hecho hoy y me va a ser imposible :(, y seguro que el error no es nada...

Dejo por aquí el código de los dos ficheros de la clase (son varias, pero como da el mismo error en todas, entiendo que con una hay):

```
/* 
 * @file: Lapiz.h
 */

#ifndef LAPIZ_H
#define LAPIZ_H

class Lapiz {
public:
    Lapiz();
    Lapiz(int dureza, std::string color, float longitud);
    Lapiz(const Lapiz& orig);
    virtual ~Lapiz();
    int getDureza();
    void setDureza(const int dureza);
    std::string getColor();
    void setColor(const std::string color);
    float getLongitud();
    void setLongitud(const float nuevaLongitud);

private:
    int _dureza;
    std::string _color;
    float _longitud;
};
#endif /* LAPIZ_H */
```

Y el fichero **.cpp**:

```
/* 
 * @file: Lapiz.cpp
*/

#include "Lapiz.h"


Lapiz::Lapiz() {
}

Lapiz::Lapiz(const Lapiz& orig) {
}

Lapiz::~Lapiz() {
}

Lapiz::Lapiz(int dureza, std::string color, float longitud):_dureza(dureza), _color(color), _longitud(longitud) {

}

std::string Lapiz::getColor() {
    return this->_color;
}

int Lapiz::getDureza() {
    return this->_dureza;
}

float Lapiz::getLongitud() {
    return this->_longitud;
}

void Lapiz::setColor(const std::string color) {
    this->_color = color;
}

void Lapiz::setDureza(const int dureza) {
    this->_dureza = dureza;
}

void Lapiz::setLongitud(const float nuevaLongitud) {
    this->_longitud = nuevaLongitud;
}
```

Muchas gracias, y disculpen si al final el error no tiene mayor trascendencia.

Comment: Debes usar `#include <string>` en el header, ¿dónde lo has colocado exactamente? Intuyo que en el cpp después de `#include "Lapiz.h"`...

Comment: Es correcto, el `#include <string>` debe ir dentro de las `header guards` del archrivo `Lapiz.h`.

Comment: Claro, efectivamente, yo estaba poniendo el #include <string> en el **.cpp**, y no en el fichero de cabecera. ¡Gracias! PD: No me funciona **Ctrl + K** para dar formato de código aquí en los comentarios.